# Sliding An element to the Right Using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#d87").append("<div id='d76'>H</div>").;

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list item</button>

</body>
</html>
<div id="d87"></div>
```

At the Moment When I press the Append List Item A box that i created through css slides in the downward direction. I want it to slide to the right, Each time the button is clicked it should shift to the right of the previous box by `100px`.

Comment: Could you please make it more clear. "it should shift to the right of the previous box by 100px" means?? There should be gap between div's of 100px ??

Comment: yes there should be a gap of 100px between the two divs

Comment: div that is at the last position that would shift or each child div ?

Comment: for example when u click the 'The append list button ' a div will be created,then when u press the button again it should create another div to the right of the previous div by a gap of 100 px and so on till the user clicks the button

Comment: You can just add this CSS for this.

Comment: This Not what i meant what i want is something like this---H H H H H assuming the h to be the box whenever the button is clicked a h should be added to the right

Comment: You have already append div#d76.Onclick this would be added at the last position insidd87  div#only and margin left would add the spacing.
http://jsfiddle.net/QLWu7/

Comment: This What i was trying to achieve thank you soo much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#d87{
  margin-left:100px; 
  float:left; 
}
```